# Relation between Parent and Children not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, foreign-keys

I'm with a problem to do the parent-child relationship in Entity Framework 6, where the parent has a list of children and one of child is the favorite one. When execute Entity Add, EF throw that error:

**Error!
Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated values.**

Example:

```
public class Child
{
    public int ChildID { get; set; }
    public string ChildName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Parent")]    
    public int ParentRefId { get; set; }

    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
}

public class Parent
{
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public string ParentName { get; set; }

    public int FavoriteChildId {get;set;}

    [ForeignKey("FavoriteChildId")]
    public Child FavoriteChild {get;set;}

    [ForeignKey("ParentRefId")]
    public ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}
```

its does not work, either:

```
 public class Child
    {
        public int ChildID { get; set; }
        public string ChildName { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Parent")]    
        public int ParentRefId { get; set; }

        public Parent Parent { get; set; }
    }

    public class Parent
    {
        public int ParentId { get; set; }
        public string ParentName { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("FavoriteChild ")]
        public int FavoriteChildId {get;set;}           

        public Child FavoriteChild {get;set;}            

        public ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: remove `[ForeignKey("FavoriteChildId")]` and `[ForeignKey("ParentRefId")]` from the Parent class and put `[ForeignKey("FavoriteChild")]` above of `FavoriteChildId` field.

Comment: @thirdDeveloper thanks for answer, i did it at first time, and didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the [fluent api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/relationships) for configurations like this, but you can try [InverseProperty annotation](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inverseproperty-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx).

```
public class Child
{
    public int ChildID { get; set; }
    public string ChildName { get; set; }

    // EF will make FK by convention
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }

    public int? FavoriteOfParentId { get; set; }
    public Parent FavoriteOfParent { get; set; }
}

public class Parent
{
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public string ParentName { get; set; }

    public int FavoriteChildId {get;set;}           
    [InverseProperty("FavoriteOfParent")]
    public Child FavoriteChild {get;set;}            

    [InverseProperty("Parent")]
    public ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}
```